# How to launch intent with custom url from inside the related app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, intentfilter

I have an android app that register a custom url scheme (let's say app://)

In the `onResume()` method of my main activity I get data from the url by calling `getIntent().getData()`.

When I browse to a web page containing such a link (like `app://action/1234`) then `getIntent().getData()` return the info I need to take appropriate action. That's fine.

Now I want to have a WebView in my app that does the same. Here's my code :

```
WebView banner = ...
banner.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.startsWith("app://")) {

            try {
                Intent i = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;

            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the link in the WebView, the `onResume()` method of the main activity is called BUT `getIntent().getData()` returns `null`.

I guess

```
Intent i = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
startActivity(i);
```

is not the good way to do it.

How should I do to reproduce the same event that happens when I click a link in the browser ?

EDIT:

My activity has `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and it seems to be the cause of my problem but if I don't set the launch mode then another copy of the activity is launched (I don't want that). I tried to handle the intent by overriding `onNewIntent()` and in the intent given to it I can see the data. But I want my app to react in the same manner with it's launched from its inside or from another app then

Is it safe to do this ? :

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    getIntent().setData(intent.getData());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
```

should do it.

Comment: That launches the activity but still no data.

Comment: @jafar: "Is it safe to do this ?" -- I would not do that. Just use the `Intent` supplied to `onNewIntent()` directly.